# Interaction of sample and rnorm function in R?

Tags: r, random

I am setting my R code for doing a Monte Carlo, however I need a sample of 1 number with a random distribution, so in order to test the function of the sample in R, I set the code below, however I do not understand the reason of the different results.

```
x <- rnorm(1,8,0)
x
#8

y <-sample(x=rnorm(1,8,0), size=1)
y
#4
```

Comment: Are you aware of what `rnorm(1,8,0)` actually means?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting `?sample`,

> If x has length 1, is numeric (in the sense of is.numeric) and x >= 1,
>   sampling via sample takes place from 1:x.

you're actually drawing from `c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)` and not from `c(8)`.

However, it works if we draw from `"character"` class.

```
as.numeric(sample(as.character(rnorm(1,8,0)), size=1))
# [1] 8
```

Comment: you can avoid the double conversion by doing `sample(rep(rnorm(1,8,0), 2), size=1)`

Comment: @Cath ahh that's clever!

Comment: @RomanLuštrik You probably intended to address the OP, I've answered regarding different behavior of the functions,

Comment: My comment was by no means meant as a judgement of you or your approach. I apologize if it came across like that.